# How do I generate C++ files with Bison and CMake to generate a tree?

Tags: c++, cmake, bison

I know how Bison works on a beginner level.
My problem is how can I force CMake to generate C++ files from the given Bison input files.
I have an existing structure for a Tree that I have to use.
This is my current buildscript that I use to learn Bison.

```
find_package(BISON)
find_package(FLEX)

BISON_TARGET(MyParser Parser.yxx ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Parser.c)
FLEX_TARGET(MyScanner Lexer.l  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Lexer.c)
ADD_FLEX_BISON_DEPENDENCY(MyScanner MyParser)

add_executable(mathParser
    ${BISON_MyParser_OUTPUTS}
    ${FLEX_MyScanner_OUTPUTS}
)
```

How would I have to change my Bison files if I wanted to generate Cpp code now?

Comment: For generate C++ file with Bison, just specify proper extension of the output file (the last argument to `bison_target` macro). [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindBISON.html) for `find_package(BISON)` contains an example with generating `.cpp` file. Most likely, other C++-specific extensions (`.cc`, `.cxx`) would also work.

Comment: @Tsyvarev it seems like the output is indeed a `.cpp` and `.hpp` but taking a look inside them reveals they are still just plain C code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Bison to use the C++ skeleton

```
%skeleton "lalr1.cc"
```

Bison also recognizes the language declaration

```
%language "c++"
```

But I don't think it is necessary.

If you're going to use the C++ API, make sure you carefully read the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#C_002b_002b-Parsers).

---

Although I'm assured that the C++ interface has advantages, I've hardly ever used it. The code generated by the C skeleton can be compiled with C++ with the proviso that you cannot use any non-trivial object as part of the semantic type `YYSTYPE`. (You can use a *pointer* but not a reference to any arbitrary C++ type, but you cannot use smart pointers.)

There is a complete example in the bison manual, however (at the link pasted earlier) and it would be worthwhile studying it for usage hints.